# colorWithPatternImage Selected image for setStroke drawing is not whole screen

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am drawing on screen with fingers.

The problem is stroke I set. I am setting the stroke as a pattern of an image which means instead of using colors I am using an image and painting with that image like a texture.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pattern"] ofType:@"png"];
[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]] setStroke]];
```

The problem is I am getting the image on the screen when I draw and it is not drawing whole screen with the pattern I use, only a portion of it till I get the image of my pattern.

In another word, the pattern does not completely paint the area I want to paint. Edges of the area stays blank and not I can not make that edge area get painted with the pattern of the image.

How can I extend the size of my pattern image or set my stroke to fill whole screen?
Let me paraphrase my question and ask it in a better way: 
Even I decrease the image size that I use as my pattern, that does not make any difference and I am not able to paint the area completely. 
How can I paint the whole area without leaving the edges blank and not painted with the pattern I use?

Thanks